# Retrieve value after a specfic string of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a value from a line after a specific string of characters.

The text files line is as follows:

```
directory, batch: xxx  Date: xxxxxx xx:xx Pulp: type

AAAAAAAA
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
eeeeeeee
```

I need to add 'Pulp: type' to my list `output[f]` and append the line. The amount of characters that makes up the pulp type varies from 3-25 characters.

This is what I currently have:

```
for f in file_list:
txtfile = open(f, 'r')
output[f] = []
for line in txtfile:
    if 'batch' in line:    #only identifier for line is 'batch'
       # What Goes Here??

for i,line in enumerate(txtfile):
    if i == 4:
        output[f].append(line)
    elif i == 5:
        output[f].append(line)
```

I don't know how to extract what I need from the line. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to extract `Pulp: type` from` directory, batch: xxx  Date: xxxxxx xx:xx Pulp: type`?

Comment: What do you actually want to extract? The end result is unclear. Show a sample of your output list perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re
a = "directory, batch: xxx  Date: xxxxxx xx:xx Pulp: type"
m = re.match('.+(Pulp.+$)', a)
my_type_string = m[1]
print(my_type_string)
```

prints:

```
Pulp: type
```

or:

```
import re

for f in file_list:
txtfile = open(f, 'r')
output[f] = []

for line in txtfile:
    m = re.match('.+batch:.+(Pulp.+$)', a)
    # if you just want the Type value, use the string
    # '.+batch:.+Pulp:(.+$)'
    if m:
        pulp_value = m[1]
        output[f].append(pulp_value)

for i,line in enumerate(txtfile):
    if i == 4:
        output[f].append(line)
    elif i == 5:
        output[f].append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the line for the index position of a substring using [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.find).

Assuming "Pulp: value" is the last segment of the line, this makes for:

```
start_pulp = line.find("Pulp:") # find the location
pulp_value = line[start_pulp:] # slice the string to get everything from the word "Pulp:" to the end of the line.
```

If "Pulp: value" does not go all the way to the end of the line, you can split the subsequent string on the following whitespace.

Example:

```
for line in txtfile:
    if "Pulp:" in line:
        start_pulp = line.find("Pulp:") # find the location
        pulp_value = line[start_pulp:]
        output[f].append(pulp_value)
```

Or you could use regex - Todd W's answer is perfectly acceptable if you go down that route.